# Error running NiftyNet Promise12 demo on multiple GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, niftynet

I am trying to duplicate the the [Promise12 demo in NiftyNet](https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/tree/dev/demos/PROMISE12).  Installed NiftyNet 0.2.2 with TensorFlow 1.3 GPU version.

After downloading the [PROMISE12 data](https://promise12.grand-challenge.org/download/) and unzipping, I modified NiftyNet's [promise12_demo_train_config.ini](https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/blob/dev/demos/PROMISE12/promise12_demo_train_config.ini) to reflect the path to my data (this was the only change).  Running on 1 GPU was successful.

Next, I changed [the `[SYSTEM]` section of the config](https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/blob/dev/demos/PROMISE12/promise12_demo_train_config.ini#L18-L22) to this:

```
[SYSTEM]
cuda_devices = ""
num_threads = 2
num_gpus = 3
model_dir = /promise12_model
```

The idea being to leverage 3 GPUs.  However, this gives the following error, repeated multiple times, looking like once per input image:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Duplicate tag imgseg/image/0 found in summary inputs
     [[Node: MergedOutputs/Merge/MergeSummary = MergeSummary[N=4, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](worker_0/DenseVNet/PyFunc, worker_1/DenseVNet/PyFunc, worker_2/DenseVNet/PyFunc, MergedOutputs/loss_device_average_)]]
     [[Node: worker_1/gradients/worker_1/loss_function_1/Mean_grad/Shape_3/_3202 = _HostSend[T=DT_INT32, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_53477_worker_1/gradients/worker_1/loss_function_1/Mean_grad/Shape_3", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1"](worker_1/gradients/worker_1/loss_function_1/Mean_grad/Shape_3)]]
```

I doubt this is the expected result, but perhaps when using multiple GPUs there are additional settings that needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

The issue/solution are discussed here: https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/issues/50